# Translate longer excel formula to VBA function (without any cell references in VBA function)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this MS Excel Formula which I would like to add to as VBA function because it is too long as a normal Excel formula.

It basically should create a text from different blocks of texts that are partially "dynamic" (meaning that they are partially dependent values in certain ranges and partially fixed) - based if certain conditions are met.

The End formula should look something like this: "Desc()" - without having to specify any cell or range because all is defined in the formula (based on the ranges it refers to) already.

```
IF(
AND(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$2))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$2)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$2))),TRUE),

LEN(
TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$2),bbinput!$C$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$2),bbinput!$D$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$2),bbinput!$E$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$2),bbinput!$F$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$2),bbinput!$G$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$2),bbinput!$H$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$2),bbinput!$I$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$2),bbinput!$J$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$2),bbinput!$K$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$2),bbinput!$L$2)))
<80
),

TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$2),bbinput!$C$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$2),bbinput!$D$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$2),bbinput!$E$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$2),bbinput!$F$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$2),bbinput!$G$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$2),bbinput!$H$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$2),bbinput!$I$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$2),bbinput!$J$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$2),bbinput!$K$2)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$2)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$2),bbinput!$L$2)),

IF(

AND(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$3))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$3))),TRUE),

LEN(
TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$3),bbinput!$C$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$3),bbinput!$D$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$3),bbinput!$E$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$3),bbinput!$F$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$3),bbinput!$G$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$3),bbinput!$H$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$3),bbinput!$I$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$3),bbinput!$J$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$3),bbinput!$K$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$3),bbinput!$L$3)))
<80
),

TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$3),bbinput!$C$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$3),bbinput!$D$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$3),bbinput!$E$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$3),bbinput!$F$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$3),bbinput!$G$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$3),bbinput!$H$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$3),bbinput!$I$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$3),bbinput!$J$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$3),bbinput!$K$3)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$3),bbinput!$L$3)),

IF(

AND(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$4))),TRUE),
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$4))),TRUE),

LEN(
TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$4),bbinput!$C$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$4),bbinput!$D$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$4),bbinput!$E$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$4),bbinput!$F$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$4),bbinput!$G$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$4),bbinput!$H$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$4),bbinput!$I$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$4),bbinput!$J$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$4),bbinput!$K$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$4),bbinput!$L$4)))
<80
),

TRIM(
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$C$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$C$4),bbinput!$C$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$D$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$D$4),bbinput!$D$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$E$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$E$4),bbinput!$E$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$F$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$F$4),bbinput!$F$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$G$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$G$4),bbinput!$G$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$H$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$H$4),bbinput!$H$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$I$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$I$4),bbinput!$I$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$J$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$J$4),bbinput!$J$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$K$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$K$4),bbinput!$K$4)&" "&
IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!$L$4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!$L$4),bbinput!$L$4)),
)))
```

I have the following code in VBA already:

```
    "=IF(" & Chr(10) & "AND(" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C3)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C3))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C4)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C4))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C5)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C5))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C6)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C6))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!" & _
    "R2C7)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C7))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C8)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C8))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C9)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C9))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C10)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C10))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C11)>0,NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(bbinput!" & _
    "R2C11))),TRUE)," & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "LEN(" & Chr(10) & "TRIM(" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C3),bbinput!R2C3)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C4),bbinput!R2C4)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C5)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C5),bbinput!R2C5)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C6)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C6),bbinput!R2C6)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(A" & _
    "ttributes,bbinput!R2C7)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C7),bbinput!R2C7)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C8)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C8),bbinput!R2C8)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C9)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C9),bbinput!R2C9)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C10)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C10),bbinput!R2C10)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C11)>0,INDIRECT(b" & _
    "binput!R2C11),bbinput!R2C11)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C12)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C12),bbinput!R2C12)))" & Chr(10) & "<80" & Chr(10) & ")," 
    & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "TRIM(" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C3)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C3),bbinput!R2C3)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C4)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C4),bbinput!R2C4)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C5)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C5),bbinput!R2C5)" & _
    "&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C6)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C6),bbinput!R2C6)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C7)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C7),bbinput!R2C7)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C8)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C8),bbinput!R2C8)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C9)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C9),bbinput!R2C9)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2" & _
    "C10)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C10),bbinput!R2C10)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C11)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C11),bbinput!R2C11)&"" ""&" & Chr(10) & 
    "IF(COUNTIF(Attributes,bbinput!R2C12)>0,INDIRECT(bbinput!R2C12),bbinput!R2C12)),"
```

Comment: Could you give us an English explanation of what the formula should be doing please.  I can see you're checking the named range `Attributes` to see if it contains anything in `bbinput` - which is a text cell reference as you're then using `INDIRECT` on it.  Your VBA is basically the same as the formula - pretty much guarantee there's a more streamlined way of doing this, but can't go through the whole lot to figure out what it does.

Comment: Just a reminder that if you use a formula with no arguments then it will not recalculate if any of the input change, so you need to use `Application.Volatile`

Comment: please show us what you had done so far, besides trying to record a macro while entering the formula...

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook : in the sheet `bbinput`, I have cells of "text blocks" in each row that are combined in the final formula if a certain criteria is met (I will come back to that). The range `Attributes` is uesed to check the text blocks in the `bbinput` sheet if they contain "dynamic" references to columns in the final output sheet the final formula is used in (e.g. if the text block cell in bbinput contains "Attribute3" is in contained in the Attributes range as well.)

Answer (score -1):

This does the first bit - I'm going home shortly so I've run out of time - but this might get you started :-)

```
public function Desc() as string
dim s as string
dim r as range 
dim att as range
set att = range("attributes")
dim ok as boolean
for each r in worksheets("bbinput").range("c2:k2")
if application.worksheetfunction.counta(att,r)>0 then
  s = s & range(r.text) & " "
end if
next r
desc=s
end function
```